# Is there a connection between Metazania and the Metaverse?

Tags: snow-crash

In the novel 'Snow Crash', is there any connection between the franchise **Meta**zania and the construct of the **Meta**verse, or are the names purely a coincidence?

Comment: Well, the prefix meta has a particular meaning, but it isn't a particularly uncommon prefix; there is no reason to think there is any specific relation between those two things, or anything else beginning with the letter M.